# Page not found (404): No Post matches the given query.

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to Create a 'Like' button on a post. a post belongs to a group. However, in my view function, Im getting a 404 error because it cant find the individual post, even though it is in the URL. here are the relevant files:

(posts/urls.py):

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/<int:group_id>/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('edit/<int:group_id>/<int:post_id>/', views.edit, name='edit'),
    path('delete/<int:group_id>/<int:post_id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('like/<int:post_id>/', views.like, name='like'),
]
```

(post/views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from groups.models import Group
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.utils import timezone

 def like(request, post_id):
     post =  get_object_or_404(Post, pk= post_id)

     if request.method == 'POST':
        post.likes_total += 1
        return redirect('/groups/index' )
        # post.save()
    else:
        return render(request, 'groups/detail.html', {'group':group})
```

(groups/detail html)

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <h5>{{post.body}}</h5>
        <p>{{post.pub_date_pretty}}</p>
        <p>{{post.author}}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'posts:edit' group.id post.id %}">Edit</a>
        <a href="{% url 'posts:delete' group.id post.id %}">Delete</a>
        <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('like').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary"> Like ({{post.likes_total}})</button></a>
{% endfor %}

  <form method ='POST' id= 'like' action="{% url 'posts:like' group.id %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" >
  </form>
```

Just don't understand why its not able to grab the post. any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing the group id to the POST request: `{% url 'posts:like' group.id %}` instead of the Post id.

Rather that using a form to send the POST request, use [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).